# For loop in C, with automatic increment or decrement depending on init and end conditions

Tags: c, for-loop

I recall seeing a very elegant "for" loop construct in C, that would increment or decrement the loop variable automatically based on whether the initial value was more or less than the end condition value.

In other words, something like this:

```
fadeUpDown(startVal, stopVal /*, stepSize */ ) {      

    // SOME CODE THAT SETS UP WHETHER TO INCREMENT OR DECREMENT

    for (int i=startVal ; i != stopVal ; ### SOME TRICKY CODE ### ) {    
        // The actual looped code      
    }
}
```

Having searched quite a bit for this code again, I have had no success, so here I am, asking if someone could help me with this.

**Edit:** We're all integers here.
Sanity check on StopVal being an integral increment / decrement of StepSize is outside the scope.
Actually, let's just **skip StepSize and make it 1**, in fact.

Comment: Thank you all, this was fantastic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

naja, e.g. simple approach:

```
int inc=startVal>stopVal?-1:1;
for (int i=startVal ; i != stopVal ; i+=inc ) {
```

Comment: +1 for calculating the increment/decrement once, instead of having extra `?:` comparison every loop round.

Comment: @hyde I think any self respecting compiler will optimize it away if startVal and stopVal don't change in the loop body.

Comment: @hyde I saw the problem with that, so I've knocked off stepSize now.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how tricky that needs to be, should be as easy as:

```
for(int i = startVal; i != stopVal; i < stopVal ? i += stepSize : i -= stepSize)
{
}
```

Note that this assumes that `stopVal` is an integer number of `stepSize` steps from `startVal`. If that's not true, it will overshoot.

It's of course possible to protect against that too, but it becomes a bit unwieldy:

```
for(int i = startVal;
    stopVal > startVal ? i < stopVal : i > stopVal;
    i < stopVal ? i += stepSize : i -= stepSize)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=startVal ; i != stopVal ;  i += (stepsize*(startVal > stopVal? -1 : 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
fadeUpDown(startVal, stopVal, stepSize) {      

    // SOME CODE THAT SETS UP WHETHER TO INCREMENT OR DECREMENT

    for (int i=startVal ; i != stopVal ; i += (startVal < stopVal) ? stepSize : -stepSize ) {    
        // The actual looped code      
    }
}
```

But the `for` loop is rather fragile in the sense that `stopVal` had better be exactly on a `stepSize` increment/decrement or your loop won't terminate properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this work with stepSize argument

```
fadeUpDown(startVal, stopVal, stepSize) {      

        for (int i=startVal, j = (startVal < stopVal); (j) ? (i < stopVal) : (i > stopVal) ; i += (j) ? stepSize : -stepSize ) {    
            // The actual looped code      
        }
}
```